# Testing behavior affected by constant defined under `config` in Rails with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application that defines the following constant in `config/environment.rb`: `RABBIT_ENABLED = ENV.key? ("RABBIT_PORT")`, which is a boolean. Meanwhile in another file `config/initializers/rabbit.rb` I have some code that looks like this:

```rb
if RABBIT_ENABLED
  options.merge(load_rabbit_env!)
else
  # do something else
end
```

This `load_rabbit_env!` method attempts to read additional environment variables using `ENV.fetch` and thus is susceptible to raising an exception. That's precisely what I wish to test.

I want to be able to write a test where I can assert the behavior of my RabbitMQ startup based on the whether `RABBIT_ENABLED` is true or false (e.g. it raises an exception if the constant is true but other env vars are missing). However, said constant appears to be impossible to stub, perhaps because of where the constant is defined by the time RSpec runs it has already loaded the Rails application and won't reread its value for the test?

I'd like to know what people would suggest I do in this situation. Ideally I wouldn't like to change where the constant is defined but I understand that it may be necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

[RSpec support stub constants](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants)

so you could create 2 contexts by stub `RABBIT_ENABLED` true or false

```rb
describe "your test" do
  context "RABBIT ENABLED"
   before(:each) do
     stub_const("RABBIT_ENABLED", true)
   end
   # ...
  end

  context "RABBIT DISABLE" do
   before(:each) do
    stub_const("RABBIT_ENABLED", false)
   end
   # ...
  end 
end
```

**update**

if you want to test the `initializer`, you could isolate the logic of the configuration then you could test that logic as normal ruby object in which you could stub constants:

```rb
# config/testable/rabbit_config.rb
class RabbitConfig
  def apply(config, *args)
   # testable logic
   if RABBIT_ENABLED
     options.merge(load_rabbit_env!)
   else
     # do something else
   end
  end
end
```

create a very first initializer `0_load_testable_config_object.rb` which will load all `testable configs` before other initializers be loaded (or you could require manually)

```rb
# config/initializers/0_load_testable_config_object.rb
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "config", "testable", "**/*.rb")].each {|l| require l }

# config/initializers/rabbit.rb
Rabbit.setup do |config|
 RabbitConfig.new.apply(config)
 # ...
end
```

now you can test `RabbitConfig` by stub_const `RABBIT_ENABLED` as above.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if you're testing logic that does not take place in an initializer itself, such as when you have a constant being used in a controller or model and you wanna test that.

Comment: @rodrigoalvesvieira i didn't read your question carefully, it turns out you want to test initializer.

Comment: @rodrigoalvesvieira you could isolate initializer logic into an object then just create the test case for that object in which you could stub `RABBIT_ENABLED` (also `ENV.fetch`), reference: https://codeclimate.com/blog/testing-code-in-a-rails-initializer/